User-defined subsection and topmarks of titleps
I am using titlesec with the pagestyles option to define headers/footers. I need the mark called by \subsectiontitle to obey the "top marks" behavior of titleps package (from the doc: top marks refer to the section immediately adjacent to the headline.). So, I load titlesec as \usepackage[pagestyles,topmarks]{titlesec}
Generally, it perfectly works. The issue: I had to completely re-define the command \subsection (see the MWE) , and to my disappointment, the subsection marks no longer follow the "top marks" rule. What to add in the definition of \subsection so that I can still have "top" subsection marks ? Thanks !
the MWE :
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[pagestyles,topmarks]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}

\renewcommand\subsection[1]{%
\noindent\refstepcounter{subsection}{\\[3pt]\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\textcolor{red}{\noindent #1\;}}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}\subsectionmark{#1}}

\titleformat{name=\section}[block]{\normalfont\large\centering\bfseries }{}{0em}{\textcolor{brown}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{} 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{} 

\makeatother


\newpagestyle{main}[\footnotesize]{
       \setfoot[][][]{}{}{}
     \settitlemarks{part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}
    \sethead[{\footnotesize\subsectiontitle}]%  even-left
            [{ %\partname~\parttitle~.~\chaptertitle~.~
            \sectiontitle}]%                              even-center
            [{{\thepage}}]%     even-right
            {{\footnotesize\subsectiontitle}}%     odd-left
            {{%\partname~\parttitle~.~\chaptertitle~.~
            \sectiontitle}}%                              odd-center
            {{{\thepage}}}%  odd-right
  }


\begin{document}
 \pagestyle{main}
 \mainmatter
 \section{section}
 \subsection{subsection1}
 \lipsum
 \subsection{subsection2}
 \lipsum
\end{document}


Just wondering. Why don't you redefine \subsection with titlesec?

Please notice in your log file the warning about the combination of titlesec (and also titleps) with KOMA-Script class scrbook. I recommend to use instead the user interface of KOMA-Script to configure sectioning commands and also scrlayer-scrpage to configure page header and footer.

@JavierBezos Because I did not manage to control the vertical space before the subsection as accurately as I do manually. And, by the way, thanks a lot for titlesec and titleps packages !

@cabohah Thanks for your remark. Actually, I posted the MWE with scrbook, but I have the same issue with the usual book class.

@JavierBezos Actually you are right, I can perfectly reproduce my "manual" definition of \subsection using titlesec (It was rather simple, I can't remember why I had to give up this idea). Anyway, I am still interested to understand what was missing in my definition so that topmarks could work.

@korks For the ‘real top marks’ to work, they must be emitted twice — not only after, but also before the title (this something titlesec/titleps does if necessary). Note the \topmark primitive doesn’t work as expected when a section starts a page, but ' titleps` fixes it with a trick (explained in the TeXbook, pp. 259-260).

@JavierBezos Thanks a lot !!
